# jQuery UI Datepicker - On start date select get date and then in end date assign a class to cell with start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am looking to pass a date from a date selection on start date input to end date input, so that I can highlight what cell was selected on start date.

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
var yourGlobalVariable;
var dateselected = '';

$('#start_date').datepicker({
    beforeShow:function(textbox, instance){
        $('#date-picker-box').append($('#ui-datepicker-div')),

        setTimeout(function () {
            instance.dpDiv.css({
                top: 30,
                left: 0
            });
        }, 0);
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("ui-calendar-one");
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ calendar.unavailable_dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    },
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

        yourGlobalVariable = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        dateselected = dateText;




        var start = $("#start_date").datepicker("getDate");
        var end = $("#end_date").datepicker("getDate");
        var currentDate = new Date(start);
        var between = [];

        while (currentDate <= end) {
            between.push(new Date(currentDate));
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }

        var test = calendar.unavailable_dates;

        let myDate = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            var newDate = new Date(test[i]);
            newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() - 1);
            myDate.push(newDate);

        }

        let arrayBetween = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < between.length; i++) {
            var stringBetween = between[i].toString();
            arrayBetween.push(stringBetween);
        }

        let arrayMyDate = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < myDate.length; i++) {
            var stringMyDate = myDate[i].toString();
            arrayMyDate.push(stringMyDate);
        }

        var atleastOne = arrayMyDate.some(function(item){
            return arrayBetween.indexOf(item) > -1;
        });

        if (atleastOne == true) {
            $("#start_date").addClass("taken-range");
            $("#end_date").addClass("taken-range");
            $(".disabled-dates-error").show();
            $(".cta button.btn").prop('disabled', true);
        }

        console.log(this);
    },
    /*altField: '#start_date',
    altFormat: 'dd M yy',*/
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy'
}); 


$('#end_date').datepicker({
    beforeShow:function(textbox, instance){
        $('#date-picker-box').append($('#ui-datepicker-div')),

        setTimeout(function () {
            instance.dpDiv.css({
                top: 30,
                left: 0
            });
        }, 0);
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("ui-calendar-two");
        if(dateselected != '') {
            $( "#end_date" ).datepicker('setDate',dateselected);
        } 
    },
    minDate: 0,

    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

        var start = $("#start_date").datepicker("getDate");
        var end = $("#end_date").datepicker("getDate");
        var currentDate = new Date(start);
        var between = [];

        while (currentDate <= end) {
            between.push(new Date(currentDate));
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }

        var test = calendar.unavailable_dates;

        let myDate = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            var newDate = new Date(test[i]);
            newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() - 1);
            myDate.push(newDate);

        }

        let arrayBetween = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < between.length; i++) {
            var stringBetween = between[i].toString();
            arrayBetween.push(stringBetween);
        }

        let arrayMyDate = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < myDate.length; i++) {
            var stringMyDate = myDate[i].toString();
            arrayMyDate.push(stringMyDate);
        }

        var atleastOne = arrayMyDate.some(function(item){
            return arrayBetween.indexOf(item) > -1;
        });

        if (atleastOne == true) {
            $("#start_date").addClass("taken-range");
            $("#end_date").addClass("taken-range");
            $(".disabled-dates-error").show();
            $(".cta button.btn").prop('disabled', true);
        }


    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        /*var newGlobalVarDate = yourGlobalVariable.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);*/

        console.log(yourGlobalVariable);
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

        return [ calendar.unavailable_dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ];


    },
    /*altField: '#end_date',
    altFormat: 'dd M yy'*/
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy'

});
```

In the screenshot attached, you can see that a start date has been selected but isn't active on the end date calendar (class active on TD has green background colour).

Any ideas of how to approach this would be great. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSGSD.png)

EDIT: This code (that is necessary to prevent range selection containing disabled days) seems to prevent active class addition:

```
function removeDisabledUnselectable () {
    $("#start_date").removeClass("taken-range");
    $("#end_date").removeClass("taken-range");
    $(".disabled-dates-error").hide();
    $(".cta button.btn").prop('disabled', false);
}

$("#start_date").on('click', function () {
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', null);
    removeDisabledUnselectable();
});
$("#end_date").on('click', function () {
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', null);
    removeDisabledUnselectable();
});
```

Comment: Where is your html? Can you add a working jsfiddle/snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Helps!

Add below code in `beforeShowDay` function of `$('#end_date')`

```
var final=new Date(yourGlobalVariable).getDate();
if (date.getDate()==final) {
  return [true, "active",""];
}
```

```js
$( function() {
var yourGlobalVariable;
var dateselected = '';
var calendar=[{
"unavailable_dates": [
"2017-09-14",
"2017-09-15",
"2017-09-16"
]
}]

$('#start_date').datepicker({
beforeShow:function(textbox, instance){
$('#date-picker-box').append($('#ui-datepicker-div')),

setTimeout(function () {
instance.dpDiv.css({
top: 30,
left: 0
});
}, 0);
$("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("ui-calendar-one");
},
beforeShowDay: function(date){
var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
return [ calendar[0].unavailable_dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
},
minDate: 0,
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

yourGlobalVariable=$(this).datepicker("getDate");
dateselected = dateText;




var start = $("#start_date").datepicker("getDate");
var end = $("#end_date").datepicker("getDate");
var currentDate = new Date(start);
var between = [];

while (currentDate <= end) {
between.push(new Date(currentDate));
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}

var test = calendar[0].unavailable_dates;

let myDate = [];
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
var newDate = new Date(test[i]);
newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() - 1);
myDate.push(newDate);

}

let arrayBetween = [];
for (let i = 0; i < between.length; i++) {
var stringBetween = between[i].toString();
arrayBetween.push(stringBetween);
}

let arrayMyDate = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myDate.length; i++) {
var stringMyDate = myDate[i].toString();
arrayMyDate.push(stringMyDate);
}

var atleastOne = arrayMyDate.some(function(item){
return arrayBetween.indexOf(item) > -1;
});

if (atleastOne == true) {
$("#start_date").addClass("taken-range");
$("#end_date").addClass("taken-range");
$(".disabled-dates-error").show();
$(".cta button.btn").prop('disabled', true);
}

console.log(this);
},
/*altField: '#start_date',
altFormat: 'dd M yy',*/
dateFormat: 'dd M yy'
}); 


$('#end_date').datepicker({
beforeShow:function(textbox, instance){
$('#date-picker-box').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
setTimeout(function () {
instance.dpDiv.css({
top: 30,
left: 0
});
}, 0);
$("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("ui-calendar-two");
if(dateselected != '') {
$( "#end_date" ).datepicker('setDate',dateselected);
} 
},
minDate: 0,

onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

var start = $("#start_date").datepicker("getDate");
var end = $("#end_date").datepicker("getDate");
var currentDate = new Date(start);
var between = [];

while (currentDate <= end) {
between.push(new Date(currentDate));
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}

var test = calendar[0].unavailable_dates;

let myDate = [];
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
var newDate = new Date(test[i]);
newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() - 1);
myDate.push(newDate);

}

let arrayBetween = [];
for (let i = 0; i < between.length; i++) {
var stringBetween = between[i].toString();
arrayBetween.push(stringBetween);
}

let arrayMyDate = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myDate.length; i++) {
var stringMyDate = myDate[i].toString();
arrayMyDate.push(stringMyDate);
}

var atleastOne = arrayMyDate.some(function(item){
return arrayBetween.indexOf(item) > -1;
});

if (atleastOne == true) {
$("#start_date").addClass("taken-range");
$("#end_date").addClass("taken-range");
$(".disabled-dates-error").show();
$(".cta button.btn").prop('disabled', true);
}


},
beforeShowDay: function(date){
/*var newGlobalVarDate = yourGlobalVariable.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);*/

console.log(yourGlobalVariable);
var final=new Date(yourGlobalVariable).getDate();
if (date.getDate()==final) {
return [true, "active",""];
} 
var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

return [ calendar[0].unavailable_dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ];


},
/*altField: '#end_date',
altFormat: 'dd M yy'*/
dateFormat: 'dd M yy'

});
});
```

```css
td.active.ui-datepicker-current-day a{
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input name="startDate" id="start_date" class="date-picker" />
<input name="startDate" id="end_date" class="date-picker" />
<div id="date-picker-box">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Amal. This code actually got me closer to where I needed to be. However, I've found something elsewhere in my code that resets the dates. I need this function as it prevents range selection containing disabled days. Any idea how to integrate your suggestion with the presence of the code (in question edit)

Comment: Can your share the css too.And just to ask,are you adding `active` class somewhere(in your question its mentioned active).And in your edit it seems to be `taken-range`.